# Dashboard working with local json data, but returning error when loading data from a WS

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2

That's will be a difficult question to explain since the data sources are local, so in case of any question, I'll be here to answer anything that you may want to know. I'll also display a lot of images and anything else that you need to help me.
I have a dashboard that do some math over a json returned from localhost (that's a sample of the json that the WS return) and all is working fine, see:

[image: working with local json file]

I was using the local json cause the WS wasn't ready to answer my requests, so I was working in a sample. Now the WS is ready and sending a JSON that looks exactly the same that I have in local, but when change the data source, the page don't work, showing an error about the json is undefined. See:
[image: Data from WS]

See the JSON return of both sources:
1) local JSON:
[image: Return from Local json]

2) WS JSON:

[image: WS JSON]

Here's all my code in codesandbox.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/q4zj7yw084

Could someone please help me? I didn't know what is causing the error and I just need this thing to finish the project.

Comment: I don't show the code since I uploaded to codesandbox.io, but If u need to see some code, please ask me and I'll show you ASAP!

Comment: Click on the error in the Inspect console, and put the code that it indicates is on line 264 of Dados.vue

Comment: if (this.canalQTD[result[i].canal] === undefined) {

Comment: In this case:
this.canalQTD = undefined
result = full array
i = 0
canal is a field of the array, which is C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is something about hoist/scope.

I change the request variable from a normal function to an arrow function and then the magic happen. Everything is working now!